# Java failed: error(Cannot allocate memory) with code 12

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have written a program to call itself after 24 hours per day. And I have 350 live running devices on the server. I need to update a report of the devices automatically every day.

```
@POST
@Path("/UpdateDevicesStats")
public static void updateAllLiveDevicesStats(){

long period = 1*24*60*60*1000;
long delay = 0;

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ArrayList<Device> devices = DeviceBuilder.getCurrentLiveDevices();
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<devices.size();i++){
                    System.out.println("Updating Device = "+devices.get(i).getId());

                    // This below line is custom code line.
                    // This is not any in-built library. 
                    SummaryBuilder.updateDBStats(devices.get(i).getId());


                    Thread.sleep(1*60*1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, delay, period);

}
```

When I run this piece of code. It goes very well for 4 to 5 hours but after that it shows me this:

```
failed: error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.

ignoring option PermSize=500m; support was removed in 8.0

ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '75' did not find a matching property.
```

Does anyone know any other better approach?

Comment: You create a new periodically scheduled task everytime `/UpdateDevicesStats` is called. Do you really want that?

Comment: Wrong approach, a chron like task would be better. And `SummaryBuilder.updateDBStats` should be checked on resource leakage, are connection, statement, resultset, files all always closed? (Use try-with-resources, and never sleep).

Comment: @JoopEggen How can I do that with chron? Because I am getting devices-list and I need to do update each and every device. Do you know better approach?

Comment: @Lino No, I need to update all the devices each day. If I do one by one in for loop, it gives me Java Heap problem. And then I thought to go with Thread.sleep() function to give some time for the next process. Do you know better approach?

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  One, check into using Streams for your collection across parallel processors.  Two, check your GC JVM settings (GC Overview --> https://stackify.com/what-is-java-garbage-collection/.  Three, I am assuming that SummaryBuilder is part of Apache Spark, are there settings that can be modified?  I agree with Joop that I would begin by monitoring mem usage.  Cheers!

Comment: @JavaJd, No, SummaryBuilder is my own custom code in my API Code.

Comment: I would definitely look into mem leaks in that class, the other thing to check is if your app has a max JVM mem limit set at startup.  Can you post the pertinent code from SummaryBuilder?

Comment: About chron usage: store and update a device list globally with a POST, and do a chron daily. Time based always is better than duration based waiting for its clear behavior. So two functions: a global device list, and a chron task.

Comment: How often is the Path "/UpdateDeviceStats" called?

Comment: I meant a chron _like_ Java lib

Comment: @Lino Yes, I want

Comment: I want to give some time before updating new device and when all the devices' updates are done then again this cycle should be run. I just want to do this. This is my whole task. If I do with chron job, there is any reference how I can parse the variable into the `TimerTask` run method. I am not geeting any idea. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with the `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();` by putting after updating the stats and after `Thread.sleep();` and also other some after statement where memory is leaked. Now it is not getting any java heap error. Thanks @JoopEggen, @JavaJd.